# Riccati equation from strange Frenet–Serret system

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, frenet-frame

If $\kappa(\mathrm{s})$ and $\tau(\mathrm{s})$ are continuous functions, then we can apply to the system of three simultaneous differential equations of first order in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.
$$
\left.\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha}{\mathrm{ds}}=\kappa \beta \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} \beta}{\mathrm{ds}}=-\kappa \alpha+t \gamma \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} \gamma}{\mathrm{ds}}=-\tau \beta
\end{array}\right\} \cdots \cdots(1)
$$
The solution of $(1)$ can be reduced to the first order differential equation and equation is so called Riceati equation.
From equation (1), we get
$$
\begin{gathered}
\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha}{\mathrm{ds}}+\beta \frac{\mathrm{d} \beta}{\mathrm{ds}}+\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d} \gamma}{\mathrm{ds}}=0 \\
\text { or, } \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{d s}\left(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2\right)=0 \\
\text { or, } \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=c
\end{gathered}
$$
If we find three continuous solutions $\alpha(s), \beta(s)$ and $\gamma(s)$ so that
$$
\underbrace{\alpha(s)=1, \quad \beta(s)=0 \text { and } \gamma(s)=0}_{\text{**I didn't understand the physical meaning of letting $\alpha(s)=1$?}}
$$

> **Question 1:** I didn't understand the physical meaning of letting $\alpha(s)=1$ and others to zero?

it follows that $\mathrm{c}=1$.
Hence $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=1 \cdots \cdots(2)$
Equation (2) can be decomposed as follows :

$$
(\alpha+i \beta)(\alpha-i \beta)=(1+\gamma)(1-\gamma)
$$

> **Question 2:** Why should I need to assume $c=1$? Is it for calculation purposes?

Let us now introduce the conjugate imaginary functions w and $-z^{-1}$, where

$$
\left.\begin{array}{c}
w=\frac{\alpha+i \beta}{1-\gamma}=\frac{1+\gamma}{\alpha-i \beta} \\
\text { and }-z^{-1}=-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\alpha-i \beta}{1-\gamma}=\frac{1+\gamma}{\alpha+i \beta}
\end{array}\right\} \cdots \cdots (3)
$$

Now, we have to express $\alpha, \beta$, $\gamma$ in terms of $w$ and $z$ From (3). we have

$$
\alpha=\frac{1-w z}{w-z}, \quad \beta=i \frac{1+w z}{w-z}, \quad \gamma=\frac{w+z}{w-z} \cdots \cdots(4)
$$

Finally, we get,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{ds}&==-\frac{i \tau}{2}-i \kappa w+\frac{i \tau}{2} w^2\\
\frac{dz}{ds}&=-\frac{\mathrm{i} \tau}{2}-\mathrm{i} z \mathrm{i}+\frac{i \tau}{2} z^2
\end{align}
$$

This type of equation has the form

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{~d}}=\mathrm{A}(\mathrm{s})+\mathrm{B}(\mathrm{s}) f+\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{s}) f^2
$$

where $A(s)=-\frac{i \tau}{2}, B(s)=-i k$ and $C(s)=\frac{i \tau}{2}$.
This equation is the so-called Riccati equation.

It will be a great help if something helps me to figure out **Question 1,2**. TIA

Comment: Connected : [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0343.pdf) or [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260361592_Bi-Hamiltonian_Structure_in_Serret-Frenet_Frame).

Comment: The cited paper seems quite advance to me right now, but I will give it a try and update you on what I understand. And thanks for your response @JeanMarie

Comment: This makes no sense for differential geometry, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are functions with values in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes, you are right @TedShifrin. But at least I want to know why should I learn this. I guess that will encourage me to memorize it or enough motivation to learn it for the exam.

Comment: Learn what? Memorize what?

Comment: In our question paper, we asked to derive the full solution ($\frac{dw}{ds}$ or $\frac{dz}{ds}$) which is 3 pages. And there are some lines which are needed to memorize (Like I double star the under text). And I have an issue with memorizing without knowing the reason @TedShifrin If you want to see the prev Q. I can add the Q here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good elementary reference for this topic is Dirk Struik's *Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry*, which discusses the connection between the Frenet frame and the Riccati equation. The complex-variables approach to describing orthonormal  frames is also used for other purposes in differential geometry, notably in the **Weierstrass-Enneper formula**  for constructing minimal surfaces.

**Preliminaries.** The Frenet frame is an orthogonal triplet of unit vectors  $T,N,B$ that evolve in a way that can be expressed as  a matrix equation for an orthogonal matrix $M$  of column vectors: $ M=[T,N,B]$. That equation is

$\dot M = SM$ where $S$ is skew-symmetric and contains entries of $\kappa$ and $\tau$.

Note that the rows of $M$ are also mutually orthogonal. Equivalently each row vector satisfies the "rigid-body" equation

(1') $\dot V(t) =\omega(t) \times V(t)$

which is a restatement of equation (1) in your posting.
Here $\omega$ is the angular velocity vector whose direction is the instantaneous axis of rotation of the rotating frame.

(P.S. A similar fact is true about the columns.)

Note that $\omega(t)$ is a vector whose entries contain $\kappa$ and $\tau$, and $\vec V=<\alpha, \beta, \gamma>$. (I will let you work out the details of obtaining (1') from (1).) Note that multiplying $\vec V(t)$ by any constant rotation matrix $R$ creates a new solution $\vec W= R \vec V(t)$ to system (1'). This gives us lots of freedom regarding the choice of initial conditions

**Answers to your questions.**

The identity $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=c$ states that our  vector has constant length. The choice $c=1$ means that length is 1. The assumption $\alpha(s) =1$  is (I suppose) simply an initial condition, NOT an identity true for all values of $s$. Perhaps there is a typo or transcription error in your notes?

PPS. There is lots of interesting geometry in the path $\vec V(t)$ traced by a point that moves on the unit sphere. It has an intrinsic notion of curvature (geodesic curvature) which can  be related to the entries of $\kappa$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MathWonk, I will definitely look at the reference. For now, can you comment something on my two questions? TIA

Comment: Edited to include the answers to your specific questions

Comment: Thanks for answering those question @MathWonk